# Расставить знаки препинания и определить, чем в предложении являются однородные члены предложения

Tags: и, пунктуация, синтаксис

В человеке должно быть всё прекрасно: и лицо, и одежда, и душа, и мысли.

Comment: Молодец Чехов! Как правильно сказал! 

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, а эти однородные члены являются подлежащими, так же как слово "всё", которое является обобщающим словом для них